# Cut a square of side 10 into 100 equal quadrilaterals, each inscribed in a circle of diameter $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Problem. *Cut a square of side 10 into 100 equal quadrilaterals, each of which is inscribable in a circle of diameter $\sqrt{3}$.*

This is a Russian Mathematics Olympiad problem ([турниры городов](http://www.turgor.ru/problems/37/vs-37-sl-avt.pdf)) for student of 8-9 grade (9-10 American equivalent).

Usually these problems have a rather short answer, not necessarily easy to come to.

So far I have managed to exclude the case in which the quadrilaterals have a right angle (and hence at least two of them).

Comment: You managed to exclude a case leading to a simple solution, it seems.

Comment: Credits to the problem poser https://mathoverflow.net/users/17581/ilya-bogdanov :D

Comment: What is the question? The problem you have mentioned is a statement...?

Comment: @u8y7541 I simply translated the problem from its original formulation in Russian. Instead of "Cut a square...", I could have written perhaps "Explain how can one can cut a square..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof (almost) without words: the side length of the largest square is $2$.

[image]